# Using multithreading in Python to create excel file

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing

Im starting to learn multithreading with Python. I want to make three functions, each function will return a dataframe, and then, those dataframes will be exported to excel.
For speeding up this process, I wanted to make three threads (for each function), but I have problem with returning the values of dataframe and with combining those results. Any help?

```
import threading
import pandas as pd
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook  

n = 100

def first(n):

    l1 = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        l1.append(i)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'first':l1})

    return df1


def secound(n):
    l2 = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        l2.append(i)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'second':l2}) 

    return df2


def third(n):
    l3 = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        l3.append(i)

    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'third':l3}) 

    return df3


with pd.ExcelWriter(file) as file:

    df1.to_excel(file, index = False, sheet_name='firs', engine='xlsxwriter') 
    df2.to_excel(file, index = False, sheet_name='second', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df3.to_excel(file, index = False, sheet_name='third', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

I know that Im making `threads` like this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = first, args = (n,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target = secound, args = (n,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target = third, args = (n,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

But I do not know how can I combine all this. Should I use multithreading or multiprocessing?

I want to speed up getting the results (df1, df2,df3) , after thats finished, I want to make an excel file. I have measured it by running these functions without return, only with print, and I get the results in half time.

This was only an example code, real codes uses lib for instagram called instaloader and instagram APIs

Comment: A) what makes you think that library allows to update that xls sheet in parallel? B) did you measure what is going on, and are you sure you are optimizing at the right place? (maybe it is a good idea to paralyze the computations, but my gut feeling is: creating that final document should happen by one thread, in controlled order).

Comment: I want to speed up getting the results (`df1`, `df2`,`df3`) , after thats finished, I want to make an excel file.
I have measured it by running these functions without `return`, only with print, and I get the results in half time

Comment: @taga I think multithreading is for tasks with intense network requests. What you are trying to do a computationally intense task. I cannot imagine you can speed up with multithreading. Usually, we limit multithreading in a single function that makes requests rather than separate functions. Because a single function is easy to be managed. What you need is muti-process.

Comment: This is just an example, real program that Im writing is for lib called `instaloader`

Comment: @GhostCat maybe `multithreading` isnt a right word, can you show me how to do this with `multiprocessing`?
This was only an example code, real codes uses lib for instagram called `instaloader` and instagram APIs.

Comment: @Yuan I have updated the question, please check it

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample function explaining how to use the multi-threading. In the question, you asked how to combine the result. My answer is to build a global list, and stores the result from your `instaloader` functions in the list. Finally, use `pd.concat` or some similar functions to process the list. 
The part that you should expect to speed up is the `instaloader` rather than `pandas`. Because `instaloader` makes network requests and consumes lots of time to wait for the response, and multi-threading helps to use the spare time to start another task.

```
import threading, queue
from  urllib import request
import pandas as pd

#this list stores all instagram url that you want to fecth
urlList = [url1,url2,....,url100000]
urlQueue = queue.Queue()
#put url into the queue
[urlQueue.put(i) for i in urlList]

#the list stores all the result. 
#In the question, you do not know how to combine the result. Just put them in a list
resultList = []

def fetchUrl(urlQueue):
    while True:
        try:

            url = urlQueue.get_nowait()
        except Exception as e:
            #the exception means you have exhausted all urls and the task finished.
            break
        try:    
            #replace this part to your own instagram function.
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            responseCode = response.getcode()

            #append the result into the list
            resultList.append(response.text)
        except Exception as e:
            continue
        if responseCode == 200:
            time.sleep(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    threadNum = 4
    for i in range(0, threadNum):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fetchUrl, args=(urlQueue,))
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

#pandas is a computationally intense function. Multi-threading does not sppeed up.
data = pd.concat(resultList)
```

Comment: So my approach is totaly wrong?
I have watched some courses and they explain multithreading by using different functions. Also my functions are different one from another.
I have tried my approach with 'print' instead of 'return' and it works good ( time is much shorter ) but I couldnt manage to to get the excel file because functions do not return anything

Comment: @taga You could add all results in a list, and process the list after the multi-threading function finished. There are lots of multi-threading topic on the internet, and a majority of them are garbage I have to say.